# respond_with not working VS render :json working in Rails 4

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in one of my API controllers:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to  :json
  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with @users
  end
end
```

This gives me the following error:

```
undefined method `model_name&#39; for ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:Class<
```

However, if I do:

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render :json => @users
  end
```

I get a proper response. Why can this be happening?

Comment: Maybe in first case you should do `@users.to_json`? Or you haven't `require 'action_controller/railtie'`

Comment: But for me both cases works.